# css flex перенос элементов

Tags: html, css

```css
.block {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.block-item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при переносе элементов, они не прилипали друг к другу с низу? Без использования margin

Comment: можно добавить `row-gap:20px` в `block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте column-gap, row-gap или просто gap

```css
.block {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  gap: 5px;
}

.block-item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
      <div class="block-item">item</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```